# Formatting currencies shows name of currency instead of symbol

Tags: javascript, number-formatting, currency-formatting

I am using `Number.prototype.toLocaleString()` like this

```
5000.70.toLocaleString('en-AU', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'EUR',
    currencyDisplay: 'symbol',
    useGrouping: true
}) // "EUR 5,000.70"
```

Expected outcome is either `"5,000.70 €"` or `"€5,000.70"`

Instead the output in Chrome is `"EUR 5,000.70"`

Comment: Try using `en-GB` instead of `en-AU`?

Comment: thanks, that does work. Unfortunately, then `"AUD"` is displayed incorrectly as `A$` instead of `$`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read up on the [`Intl.NumberFormat()` specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat#Parameters), the possible values of `currencyDisplay` are:

- "`symbol`" to use a localized currency symbol such as €, this is the default value,
- "`narrowSymbol`" to use a narrow format symbol ("$100" rather than "US$100"),
- "`code`" to use the ISO currency code,
- "`name`" to use a localized currency name such as "`dollar`",

So, it looks like it is a matter of setting `currencyDisplay` to `narrowSymbol` to achieve what you want:

```js
const x = 5000.70.toLocaleString('en-AU', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'EUR',
    currencyDisplay: 'narrowSymbol',
    useGrouping: true
});

console.log(x); // €5,000.70
```